# In Google maps Geocoding API response getting to many address components. Which one have to use?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am using Google Map Geocoding API to get the Address. But this API providing many address components. Which one to use?
And formatted_address sometimes show just numbers or few text, not the appropriate address. Then how to Solve this problem? please guide.

This API response is Given below.

[Google Maps Geocoding API response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYhIc.png)

My Geocoding API is working fine. It is sending me formatted_address also more than one address_component. I want to know which result should i use.
result I am getting,

```
0: {address_components: Array(4), formatted_address: "Unnamed Road 13963, Saudi Arabia", geometry: {…}, place_id: "ChIJv7xhkmy4Lj4ROLOQaEMMlQE", types: Array(1)}

1: {address_components: Array(3), formatted_address: "13958, Saudi Arabia", geometry: {…}, place_id: "ChIJm51MQo7HLj4RGmz_y_H_iYU", types: Array(1)}

2: {address_components: Array(2), formatted_address: "Riyadh Province Saudi Arabia", geometry: {…}, place_id: "ChIJwS4u9s4DJz4R1GIN45_BpL4", types: Array(2)}

3: {address_components: Array(1), formatted_address: "Saudi Arabia", geometry: {…}, place_id: "ChIJQSqV5z-z5xURm7YawktQYFk", types: Array(2)}
```

which one have to use. Index 0, 1,2 or 3

Comment: Which address components are you looking for?  If you want the complete address, then formatted_address is what you want.  If you are getting unexpected results, that is probably due to how you are calling it.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (FYI- pictures of debugger output are almost always useless by themselves)

Comment: My Geocoding API is working fine. It is sending me formatted_address also more than one address_component.

Comment: Depends on what you want.  The "types" array tells you what that component is.

Comment: You can see there are objects i am getting from google geocoding API. I can get the "types" array in every  objects. from [0] or [1] or [2] or [3]. I want to know which one is the best practice to use. I am using now "result[0]" data.

Comment: Look in the types array.  What type of information do you want from the geocoded location?  Find the entry with that in the types array and use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need Street addresses (address that is accepted by the Post Office), I would suggest using the `formatted_address` field as this is supposed to be the human-readable address, and it should honor the country's address format.

Using the Address components, like dynamically printing them in sequence can be tricky, as different result `types` like `postal_code` do not follow the `formatted_address` sequence.